# dynamically change the container in different pages which open the same external view by in Dojo mobile ViewController.openExternalView

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to load an external view on different container inside different pages. The container is able to load. But the container does not change. Which means, first I click "Button1", the external view will display inside 'container1'. Then I click "Button2", the external view will display. But if I view source, it is inside 'container1'.

Could anyone please suggest me how to change the container dynamically which display the external view?

I'm doing Hybric Mobile application using

- dojo 1.9.3

Following is the snippet that I'm trying.

page1.html

```
<div id="page1_container" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View>
 <button id="btn1" onClick="loadExternalView('container1');" value="Button1"><br>
</div>
<div id="container1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
 <!-- An external view is loaded here when clicking the button above -->
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="page2_container" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View>
 <button id="btn2" onClick="loadExternalView('container2');"><br>
</div>
<div id="container2" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
 <!-- An external view is loaded here when clicking the button above -->
</div>
```

externalView.html

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="vExternalView">
 <div id="c" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Container">
  <span>I'm from External View</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function loadExternalView(container){
 var vc = dojox.mobile.ViewController.getInstance();
 vc.openExternalView({
  url:"externalView.html",
  transition:"slide"
 },dijit.registry.byId(container).containerNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vc.openExternalView() will only load the view if it has not already been loaded, since it was loaded on the first click of "Button1", it will not be reloaded inside container2 when you click "Button 2", which by the way is a good thing, because if it did you would have an error due to duplicate id's.